# Send PDF, docx, etc. files from node.js

Tags: node.js, file, pdf, download, send

I'm trying to send file's content requested by user using AngularJS on clientside.

This is how I send file from node:

```
res.download(filePath, req.param('fileName'));
```

And this is how I read and save file in Angular:

```
$http.get('/attachment/' + req.fileName, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    var element = angular.element('<a/>');
    var file = '';
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
        file += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    element.attr({
        href: 'data:application/force-download,' + encodeURI(file),
        target: '_blank',
        download: fileName
    })[0].click();
});
```

It seems to work but only for trivial files (TXT, CSV etc.) but after requesting PDF client get file with proper page count but all pages are blank.
I suppose it must be something wrong with content encoding.

Have anyone had similar issue and already fixed it?

Comment: is this solved? i'm facing similar issue in my environment